# javascript как добавить клаcc?

Tags: javascript

Помогите изменить добавить класс на checked

```js
var inputText= document.getElementById("inputText");
var hideShow= document.getElementById("hideShow");

ButtonAdd.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var list = document.getElementById('list');

  var check = document.createElement("input");
  check.type = "checkbox";
  check.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(text.textContent);
  });

  var text = document.createElement("span");
  text.textContent = inputText.value;

  var label1 = document.createElement('label');

  label1.appendChild(check);
  label1.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(label1);
});

hideShow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll("#list input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  checks.forEach(item => item.parentNode.parentNode.className="hides");
});
```

```css
.hides{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
        <label class="hides">
<input type="checkbox"><span>dsfd</span>
        </label>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="" id="inputText">
<button id="hideShow">hide selected</button>
<button id="ButtonAdd">Add</button>
```

Comment: внутри `ul` должны располагаться только `li` либо `script`, `template`

Comment: оно добавляет <input type="checkbox"><span>dsfd</span> и к нему нужно добавить класс hides вот так <input type="checkbox" class="hides"><span>dsfd</span> к выбранному а он добавляет его к ul

Comment: checks.forEach(item => item.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(item.parentNode)) так он удаляет выбранный элемент, а нужно добавить класс к нему что бы скрыть

Comment: внутри ul <input type="checkbox"><span>текст с input</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри `ul` должны располагаться только `li`, либо [*script-supporting elements*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-2) в которые входят `<script>` и `<template>`.

---

Для установки класса нужному `label` нужно посмотреть где расположен этот элемент относительно `input`.

```
<label class="hides">
    <input type="checkbox"><span>dsfd</span>
</label>
```

Из разметки видно, что `label` является родительским элементом, следовательно, для доступа к нему нужно использовать [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

```
item.parentNode.className="hides"
```

Comment: оно к  выбранному добавляет, но и к ul тоже в итогу все скрывается через item.parentNode.className="hides"

Comment: @recile, если item - это input, `item.parentNode` никак не может быть `ul`, следовательно это делает другой код. Например тот, который у тебя в вопросе, вполне добавляет `ul`

Comment: блин точно у меня был еще один код) Спасибо большое